# What was the name of this children's book?

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult, childrens-novel

I read a book when I was in middle school about 10-12 years ago (2004-2006).

Main character was a teen girl, her stepmother tried to kill her (not directly, subtly), her father doesn't believe her, she goes away then on some adventures and she founds a mask or something that grants her power (bear or wind). Some details may be incorrect apart from that the main character was girl.

I read this book in a day but couldn't find the sequel at that time (it was at a city library). Now it stuck on my brain like a splinter and you know the rest.

If anyone of you can remember this YA/children book it would be awesome.

Comment: So, you are certain that it's part of a series? Or were you just left with the impression that it was unfinished? And "bear or wind" is an odd range of powers... is there anything that you remember that suggests it being one of those two?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think it was series because I feel like I remember there was "First book of ..." written at cover (in my language). I remember there was a mask (Don't know if she finds at start or at the end) maybe it was shaped as bear but grants wind, frankly I am not sure. One more thing I don't exactly clear is maybe she had a roommate or something, she wasn't staying at her own home but academy dorm something like that? And technology was like 15th-16th century instead of modern day I think.